# TypeScript generics create instace

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a factory for instantiating my classes with generics. Checked out [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and it all works perfectly. In short, this works just fine:

```
class Person {
    firstName = 'John';
    lastName = 'Doe';
}

class Factory {
    create<T>(type: (new () => T)): T {
        return new type();
    }
}

let factory = new Factory();
let person = factory.create(Person);

console.log(JSON.stringify(person));
```

Now define class Person in `directory`:

```
export class Person extends BasePerson {
    firstName = 'John';
    lastName = 'Doe';
}
```

And when I import `Person` from other package:

```
import { Person } from "./directory"

class Factory {
    create<T>(type: (new () => T)): T {
        return new type();
    }
}

let factory = new Factory();
let person = factory.create(Person);
```

I get error:
`Argument of type 'typeof Person' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => Person'`

How can I get a value of `Person` instead of `typeof Person`?

Using TypeScript 3.7.2 and Node v10.13.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem here was a parent class of `Person` -> `BasePerson`. `BasePerson` expected an argument in its constructor, so when I tried to call `factory.create(Person)`, `Person` actually was an `typeof` because it expected an argument for base class constructor. Problem was solved by deleting the constructor in base class and injecting a property via ioc container, in my case [Inversify](http://inversify.io).

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this for me please?

```
import { Person } from "./directory"

class Factory {
    create<T>(type: (new () => T)): T {
        return new type();
    }
}

let factory = new Factory();
let person = factory.create(new Person);
```

Comment: thumbs up for the quick answer :) it is not a valid statement though, but I solved it. It is a little embarrasing, i had a parent class that expected an argument in its contructor, removed it and now everything works perfectly!

Comment: @pavle could you please add an answer how you solved your problem or - if this is really the correct answer - mark it with the green hook?

Comment: Your welcome @pavle, as mentioned by messerbill it might be a good idea to post your solution for any future folk who are experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: @InchHigh done. Inheritance was the problem, but with better dependency composition, problem was solved. Composition over inheritance!

Comment: Good stuff :) - Glad you sorted it.